# Warning: a promise was created in a handler - bluebird

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm getting below warning error, please guide me to fix it.

> Warning: a promise was created in a handler at anonymous> (/opt/testproj/node_modules/pipeworks/pipeworks.js:72:17but was not returned from it, see http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it
>   at new Promise (/opt/testproj/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)

**Sample code**:

```
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
const options = {
                  promiseLib: bluebird
                };
const pgpromise = require('pg-promise')(options);
const connectionString = `postgres://${user}:${password}@${host}:${port}/${database}`; 
const db = pgpromise(connectionString);


db.func('student__find_by_id', [id])                                       
.then((data) => {                                                                                                                   
  return res.json(data);
}).catch((err) => {
   log.error(err);                                                                                                              
});
```

Comment: Your code looks too simple. Either you are missing a return statement somewhere, or the posgres library isn't chaining all of its nested promises. If the error-stack is being honest, then it's a 3rd-party library that is being used by one of your libraries, that has the error. Not you. In that case, use a different promise library, or see if you can turn off the warning.

Comment: Thank you @Norguard for your immediate response. Yes, it is simple code which gives warning, i don't know what is wrong with this code, i kept return statement wherever it is needed. I'm not getting this warning error if i don't use bluebird as By default, pg-promise uses ES6 Promise(https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise#promiselib).

Comment: The code shown here cannot throw that error. You must have an issue elsewhere in your code. Test coverage in `pg-promise` is very comprehensive, and such standard situations are covered 100 times over, using `Bluebird` as the promise library.

Comment: @Norguard, yes as you said error was in swagger middleware(3rd party library). I have fixed it, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As per my earlier comments, the code shown here cannot throw the error you describe. And situations like this one are comprehensively covered within [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) tests.

You should use [Bluebird's Long Stack Tracing](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.config.html) feature to correctly identify the code that results in this error:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.config({
    longStackTraces: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you Vitaly, i have added longStackTraces: true, but no luck. It shows same error message, nothing more than that.

Comment: @thavaamm Does it not show you the exact line where the problem occurs? It absolutely should.

Comment: If you think your code is correct, or simply want to disable those warnings, you can do `longStackTraces: false`, which will hide those types of errors. Not a great solution in general, but as a temporary, till you may finally find out what is going on... ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have fixed the issue, issue was in swagger middleware(3rd party library).